# Python jsonschema not Raising an Exception

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonschema

I am attempting to validate a JSON schema like this:

```
try:
    print('instance {}'.format(json))
    print('schema {}'.format(schema))

    val = validate(instance=json, schema=schema)
    print('validation {}'.format(val))

except (ValidationError, Exception) as error:
    raise InvalidSchemaJSON from error
```

Where the JSON is:

```
{
    "t": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9",
    "p": "password"
}
```

And it needs to be validated against:

```
{
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        't': {'type': 'string'},
        'p': {'type': 'string'},
    },
    'required': ['t', 'p']
}
```

---

I've tried modifying the schema in order to purposely set off an exception to:

```
{
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        't1': {'type': 'string'},
        'p1': {'type': 'string'},
    },
    'required': ['t', 'p']
}
```

And no exception was raised.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As this was down to a typo, I've suggested this be closed, as per closure guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modified schema you still have required keys as `'required': ['t', 'p']`

It should be `'required': ['t1', 'p1']`